# Using a variable in sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the following command to insert a string variable to a file after line 1:

```
sed '1a\"$str_builder"' certs.json > certs-new.json
```

I have used double quotes around the variable as the answers in other similar posts have said to do (so don't mark as duplicate pls), but it still doesn't work and just inserts the string `$str_builder`

The file `certs.json` looked like:

```
[
    {
        "url" : "www.google.com",
    .
    .
```

And `certs-new.json` looks like:

```
[
$str_builder
    {
        "url" : "www.google.com",
    .
    .
```

Comment: Use double-quotes to expand shell variables

Comment: @Inian read post clearly please

Comment: What value you are storing in variable `str_builder`?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam just a string block to insert as a new JSON entry

Comment: is it like "something" : "value"?

Comment: Don't use `sed` (a line-oriented tool) to edit JSON (a structured langauge) at all. Use something like `jq` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes around the whole thing and remove the backslash.

```
sed "1a$str_builder" certs.json > certs-new.json
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work unfortunately, just writes `$str_builder`

Comment: Ah - if you're using sed to insert lines then you don't need the backslash character.  Try without it: `sed "1a$str_builder" certs.json > certs-new.json`

Comment: Thanks this worked!! If you edit your original answer or write a new one I can accept it

Comment: Just one thing, it's removing the first backslash and so the first tab `\t` is coming through as just a `t`, I've tried changing it to `\\t` but it's still coming through as just `t`

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes inhibit variable expansion. You need to use double quotes.

```
sed "1a$str_builder" certs.json > certs-new.json
```

If you want double quotes inside the outer quotes, the inner ones need to be escaped.

```
sed "1a\"$str_builder\"" certs.json > certs-new.json
```

You'd probably be better off using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to modify your JSON data, though. It's a smarter tool designed expressly for JSON manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, but this also inserts a pair of `"` around the expanded variable. And thanks for the tip about jq!

Answer (score 0):

I tried `sed` command in my system from the below two answer and got error `sed: command garbled:` hence quickly giving below solution without a `sed` command for the time being. Will check once get time how to fix it with `sed`.

```
 #first print the first line of file certs.json
 head -1 certs.json > certs-new.json
 #Now insert value of variable str_builder into certs-new.json as second line
 echo "$str_builder" >> certs-new.json

 #now insert all the lines except first line from certs.json to certs-new.json
 tail +2 certs.json >> certs-new.json
```